# How do I change the Gradle version the Eclipse SpringSource plugin uses?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, springsource

Note this is for the SpringSource plugin.

When I try to import a Gradle project in Eclipse I am getting the following error:

> Project location doesn't exist; See error log for details.

The stacktrace error is basically this:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Project location doesn't exist

I did some research, and a Gradle defect (https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3158) mentions that error handling was improved with a more useful error message, including the project location.

I have Gradle 1.7 now on my machine; however Eclipse/Springsource keeps using Gradle 1.2. How do I get it to use 1.7 (or even 1.8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend to check "Preferences->Gradle->Use Gradle wrapper's default" and install the [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) for all builds in question. Then Eclipse will automatically pick the right Gradle version for each build (and nobody has to install Gradle manually).

Comment: My team is supposed to be using Gradle 1.2 by default; if I change the wrapper default to point to my folder, will that allow me to use 1.7 temporarily? And yes, I realize sticking with 1.2 seems odd. Pushing to have us upgrade.

Comment: Gradle Wrapper assumes you need a gradle.bat - sadly rules out Mac OS X users.

Comment: The `wrapper` task also generates a `gradlew` shell script for *nix.